# Increasing & decreasing function

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Find the interval in which the function $$f(x) = 3x^3 - 24x^2 + 14x + 6$$ is increasing and decreasing.

Could somebody do this question and explain the different steps involved.

Thank you in anticipation of your co-operation.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: $f'(x)>0\implies f(x)$ is increasing

Answer (score 3):

I'll outline the steps involved, and leave you to execute the steps:

**Steps:**

- Calculate the first derivative, $f'(x)$.

---

- Then solve the inequality: $$f'(x) >0$$
- The solutions to that inequality will give you the values of $x$ over
  which $f(x)$ is increasing.

---

- Determine the intervals over which $$f'(x) < 0$$
- The solution to the second inequality will give you the intervals over which $f(x)$ is decreasing.

Comment: f'(x) = 9x^2 - 48x + 14

Comment: To solve this equation do I need to use the 'quadratic formula' as I cannot factorize it in the normal way.

Comment: Nice work on the derivative. Yes, use the quadratic formula to determine when $f'(x) = 0$. The use those two values to divide the domain into three intervals, and test a point in each interval to see whether $f'(x) > 0$ or $f'(x) \lt 0$. The sign of that number you test (positive or negative) will determine if increasing on that interval (+), or decreasing on the interval.

Comment: Thanks for getting back so soon.

Comment: when I use the quadratic formula I get (8 + 0r - 5square root of 2)/3. (I cannot get the normal inequality or square root signs on my pc).

Comment: @amWhy: Nicely laid out and discourse +1